Female hacker tries to prove her innocence
Can any one tell which hacking movie is that where the actress plays a professional hacker who was working as a government agent but was set up by some bad hacker as such things went against her and she runs away; cops started searching for her. In order to prove her innocence and hide safely, she goes to meet her friend whom she can trust; he was also a hacker and was jailed earlier for hacking activities, and there was another guy with a van with tech stuff inside. In total now three guys - one girl, two men... In the rest of the story good guys helps her to locate and find the bad hacker by hacking into several computers all day and night writing script codes. The bad hacker claims to be the best hacker of all time and no one can defeat him, he was trying some cyber crime and the heroine and her friends were continuously trying to defeat his activity. At the end the bad guy made her face broadcasted on the big screen in the streets where she was supposed to commit her crime in front of whole world which she has never done; she was actually supposed to push the ENTER button on the keyboard and show it to the world that she was doing the crime. But at last things changed and the bad guy got killed. She gets her job back and her friend, the guy who was jailed earlier for hacking activities, also gets the job as a professional hacker.
I can't remember the movie name and searched the entire internet but can't find this movie listed. I dare hardly anyone will be able to answer which movie it is.

Sounds like the 2012 nine-part web movie Cybergeddon. An online recap:

The movie revolves around Chloe Jocelyn, a prodigy of the FBI Cyber Crime division. She is framed for a crime she didn’t commit, forcing her to go on the run and team up with Chase ‘Rabbit’ Rosen, a black hat hacker and her old flame, Frank Parker, to prove her innocence and to discover who is behind the attack.

Here's the trailer. The scene you're describing near the end (the evil hacker planning to release 'cybergeddon' broadcasts the heroine's image on giant screens around the world and forces her to press 'enter' by threatening to kill her mother) is in part 8 here.
